# How to access a node from kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

In this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-ip) they use `u@node$` to define that the command is done from a node in a cluster. But how do you get to the node from kubectl?

It is well described how to get to a pod `u@pod$`

Comment: I don't think you can ssh into a node using google kubernetes engine.

Comment: of course you can ssh into a node in Kubernetes Engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apiserver can be used as a HTTP proxy (as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster#accessing-services-running-on-the-cluster)) to hit endpoints on Nodes, but I assume you need an SSH session which won't help.

On GKE you can SSH into your nodes using `gcloud` as follows:

- `gcloud compute instances list`
- `gcloud compute ssh <nodeName>`

Answer (score 3):

On GKE you simply select your cluster and click on SSH button. If from the command line, then:

```
gcloud compute ssh NODE --zone ZONE
```